How to get datadog application key scopes
I'm trying to access multiple datadog apis and to access them I require the api and application key of the datadog. But is there any way to check the scopes or the permissions of the application key before hand through an API, so that I can validate if my application key has all the necessary scopes/permissions required?
I've tried different apis like the ones below but they only seem to give out all the permissions and roles that are available but not the ones assigned to the current application key.

https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/authentication/#validate-api-key
https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/roles/#list-permissions
https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/roles/#list-roles


have you tried https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/key-management/#get-an-application-key? The response should include the scopes. That's the API documentation for key management.
